# Jinja2 render context not applied to imported templates

Tags: python, jinja2

I noticed context variables do not seem to apply to imported templates. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

I have a template containing a macro and another template that imports the macro and uses it.

```
macro = ("{% macro some_macro() %}"
         "{{ func('a') }}"
         "{% endmacro %}")
use_macro = ("{% from 'macro' import some_macro %}"
             "{{ some_macro() }}")
loader = jinja2.loaders.DictLoader({'macro': macro,
                                    'template': use_macro})
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
template = env.get_template('template')
```

Now when I try to render the template with `func` in the context it fails because `func` is undefined:

```
rendered = template.render(func=lambda x: x)
```

It does work when `func` is in the globals:

```
env.globals.update(func=lambda x: x)
rendered = template.render()
```

Is this as intended or does this seem like a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use import with context:

```
use_macro = ("{% from 'macro' import some_macro with context %}"
             "{{ some_macro() }}")
```